# Why did my Nether Portal spawn on the roof of the Nether?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I am making a datapack, and started up a world, then built a portal so I could travel to the nether to test some things...

Except my portal spawned me on the nether roof.

According to Google, portals "try to generate at a similar Y value". The portal was built in the overworld at Y=68, yet the portal generated on the roof (Y=128). I was wondering why this happened and what conditions would cause this to happen.

In case it is relevant, I did notice (when flying down in spectator mode) that where I spawned was above a massive lava ocean, could that have forced it to spawn on the roof as there was no land?

Comment: Is your question “why” or how to deal with being on the roof?

Comment: So you spawned on top of bedrock?

Comment: Yes, and I was just wondering why.

Comment: Not sure how you did this, but don't remove it till you have another access point.  Being above bedrock can be super useful.  You prolly know this already, if so srry for the useless comment =)

Answer (score 2):

The portal generated on the roof most likely because there were no valid portal spawn locations within 16 blocks of the portal destination. Although, it actually should've spawned an obsidian platform below the roof of the nether. So honestly, seems like you may have just encountered a glitch.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_portal#Portal_creation)

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know why it happens, but you can fix this by relocating your portal at least 1,000 blocks away from your existing portal and trying again (yup, seems far, but this is the only solution).
You can also try building your portal underground once you reach the new location 1,000 blocks away, to maximize your chances of not spawning on the nether roof again.

Comment: I was just wondering why it happened and if I need to worry about it happening again? Because if I were in survival that would be a problem.